# How to get Depth map image(jpg) of an JPG image in Android? (JAVA/KOTLIN)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-camera2, icafe

I am using a Java library named icafe(https://github.com/dragon66/icafe) for generating a depth map image from a jpg image. It can extract and insert XMP as well as ExtendedXMP.

One of the use-case for the ExtendedXMP is for Google's depth map data which is a grayscale image hidden inside the actual image as metadata, and in the case of JPEG, as XMP data. The following is an example image and the extracted depth map:[image]

The original image comes from [here](http://stereo.jpn.org/kitkat/indexe.html)

I have used the libraries following code to get a depth map image:

```
JPEGTweaker.extractDepthMap()
```

More details of how we achieved the output with this library can be found [here](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe/blob/master/src/com/icafe4j/test/TestMetadata.java).

**But the problem is that the only sample pictures are providing outputs. Other images like pictures taken on pixel 2 xl or pixel 3(Even in the portrait mode) are not working.**

*The library does not ensure that it will generate depth map image from all the jpg images from Android Camera, But is there any workaround in camera 2 API that can help me to find the depth map photo?*